# Cycle 'Shape Data' in Visio

Tags: vba, visio

Apologies this seems rather basic, but i can't seem to find adequate documentation on it.
I essentially need to cycle through the rows in "Shape Data" on the shape sheet, using VBA in Visio 16.  The code i'm looking for (I imagine) will look somewhat like this:

```
sub printLabelsAndProps()
    for each x in UnknownGroupOfThings
        debug.print x.prop.DataAndDocuments
        debug.print x.prop.Supports
    Next
end sub
```

Help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you know that all your shapes have "DataAndDocuments" and "Supports" properties, you could use something like the code below (otherwise you may need to check if the shape has those properties using `.CellExists`). Also if your cells contain calculated strings, then you should use `.ResultStr()` instead of `.Formula`. If those values are numbers, you can even go without `.Formula`

```
Sub printLabelsAndProps()
    For Each x In ActivePage.Shapes
        Debug.Print x.Cells("Prop.DataAndDocuments").Formula
        Debug.Print x.Cells("Prop.Supports").Formula
    Next
End Sub
```

If you want to cycle through all properties for a single shape, you could go with something like this:

```
Sub showAllProperties(x As Shape)
    For i = 0 To x.Section(visSectionProp).Count - 1
        Debug.Print x.CellsSRC(visSectionProp, i, visCustPropsLabel).Formula
        Debug.Print x.CellsSRC(visSectionProp, i, visCustPropsValue).Formula
    Next
End Sub
```